# Web API not working with convention based routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web API which uses convention based routing in ASP.NET Core 1.1. I have the following code in the `Configure` method of my `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "api/inventory",
        defaults: new { controller = "Inventory" });
});
```

I have another `InventoryController.cs` class containing:

```
public class InventoryController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I expect that I will receive `["value1","value2"]` when I call `api/inventory`, but that is not the case. I receive a 404 instead. I am new to ASP.NET and have tried almost everything I could think of and am at wit's end. I'll note here that using a `RouteAttribute` makes everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing it like this

```
  app.UseMvc(config => {
            config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
                ,defaults: new { controller="App", action="Index"}
                );
        });
```

and your class will look like

```
[Route("api/Inventory")]
public class InventoryController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IEnumerable<string> Get()
  {
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
  }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, using a `RouteAttribute` makes everything work fine. But I want to know why using conventional routing doesn't work.